# Using dplyr quosures with mutate()

Tags: r, dplyr, quosure

Reading the [Programming with dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html) guide, I get a unexpected error.

In fact, trying the examples with `summarize` works quite right, but if I try similar things with `mutate`, the code won't run.

Here is my code :

```
df = data.frame(A=c(464,3465,48,3415,357,21,657), B=c(12,15,985,35,67,13,467))

df %>% 
  mutate(x = A-B) %>%
  pull(x)
#returns the good output :
#[1]  452 3450 -937 3380  290    8  190

get.diff = function(var1, var2, data=df){
  var1 = enquo(var1)
  var2 = enquo(var2)
  data %>% 
    mutate(x = (!!var1 - !!var2)) %>%
    pull(x)
}
get.diff(A, B)
returns an error
```

Here is the error :

> Error in !var2 : invalid argument type

I tried a lot of thing, but this is the closest I got to the guide samples.

What did I miss ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need parentheses around each "bang bang" / unquoting (`!!varX`) :

```
mutate(x = ((!!var1) - (!!var2))) %>%
```

Full code:

```
df = data.frame(A=c(464,3465,48,3415,357,21,657), B=c(12,15,985,35,67,13,467))

  df %>%
    dplyr::mutate(x = A-B) %>%
    pull(x)
  #returns the good output :
  #[1]  452 3450 -937 3380  290    8  190

  get.diff = function(var1, var2, data=df){
    var1 = enquo(var1)
    var2 = enquo(var2)
    data %>%
      dplyr::mutate(x = ((!!var1) - (!!var2))) %>%
      pull(x)
  }
  get.diff(A, B)

  [1]  452 3450 -937 3380  290    8  190
```

Comment: This is very annoying : your code works like a charm in a new session, but fails with the same error in my session.

Comment: OK I get it. I had `plyr::mutate` and not `dplyr::mutate`. Such similar packages, working together and providing duplicated method which don't works the same is very unconvenient...   
Thanks for your help !

Comment: You're welcome. I added a dplyr reference for mutate to enhance reproducibility,